# Automatizar execução de script R

Tags: cmd, r, bat

Tem um script na liguagem R que funciona perfeitamente no Rstudio. Para automatizá-lo, executa toda terça feira as 15:00, resolvi criar um arquivo .bat e agendar a execução dele pelo agendador de tarefas, com os seguintes comandos:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\Rscript.exe" --vanilla "H:\COP\00 - PROJETOS\06 - Carteira  (fase teste)\Testes Automacao\exportacaoPlanilhaBloomberg.R"
```

Entretanto, no script tem uma referência a um arquivo acentuado, e quando executo o .bat, pelo cmd tenho

```
`Erro: `path` does not exist: '//madreperola/GOP/COP/SALDO/SALDO FUNDO PREVIDENCIÃ?RIO.xlsm'`
```

Não posso alterar o nome do arquivo (SALDO FUNDO PREVIDENCIÁRIO.xlsm) pois há inúmeras outras referências a ele, e nem todas feitas por mim. Há algum outro meio de automatizar a execução do script, ou resolver este problema sem ter que alterar  o nome do arquivo?

Comment: No script do R, o bat  é só para executar o script mesmo!

Answer (score -1):

Essa não é uma resposta completa, mas penso que pode te ajudar. Eu não uso Windows, então não consigo testar propriamente.

Uma possível solução para o problema do acento:

Dentro do script R, ao invés de você escrever o `path` completo, tente dar um `paste0` com o `setwd` e pegar o nome do arquivo via `list.files()`. Quando você der um `list.files()`, veja o nome dele, e se é factível você utilizar alguma regra de expressão regular nele.

Uma solução para o caminho em si:

Outra coisa: Veja que na saída do erro, o caminho começa com 2 barras: `//`, e não apenas `/`. Veja se esse não pode ser o seu erro também.

Escrevi aqui, devido ao limite de caracters no comentário.